# Removing drawings without overriding previous ones on pygame -Python

Tags: python, graphics, pygame

I am trying to create a paint app, I got help from this previous post I've opened:

[The previous question I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61295811/saving-history-of-drawing-in-pygame-in-order-to-implement-ctrl-z) about how to implement ctrl Z.

However now I get into another proble, which is when I press ctrl Z it does delete what I drew (the last one as it works like a stack) but if you draw 2 shapes one over another, then press ctrl Z it deletes some parts of the previous shape, for example:

[image]
And then pressing ctrl Z leaves me with:

[image]

How do I fix it so it won't leave a blank space there?

my code:

```
from collections import deque
from DrawEntity import DrawEntity

import pygame as pg


WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK =  (0, 0, 0)
SCREEN_SIZE = (1100, 800)
DrawEnt = deque()
brush = 3


def draw(window):
    if len(DrawEnt) > 0:
        d_Ent = DrawEnt[-1]

        mouseX, mouseY = pg.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pg.mouse.get_pressed()
        if click[0]:
            circle = pg.draw.circle(window, BLACK, (mouseX, mouseY), brush)
            d_Ent.add(circle)





def main():
    global brush
    running = True
    window = pg.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE)
    window.fill(WHITE)


    while running:
        clock.tick(1800)

        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                running = False

            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    DrawEnt.append(DrawEntity())
                elif event.button == 4:
                    brush += 1 if brush < 30 else  0
                elif event.button == 5:
                    brush -= 1 if brush > 0 else 0



            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:

                if event.key == pg.K_z and pg.key.get_mods() & pg.KMOD_LCTRL:


                    if len(DrawEnt) > 0:
                        ent = DrawEnt.pop()
                        for entity in ent.entity:
                                pg.draw.circle(window, WHITE, entity.center , entity.width)




            draw(window)

        pg.display.flip()
    #end main loop
    pg.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    pg.init()
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    main()
```

DrawEntity.py:

```
class DrawEntity:
def __init__(self):
    self.entity = []

def add(self, toAdd):
    self.entity.append(toAdd)

def remove(self):
    self.entity = []

def __str__(self):
    return ' '.join(map(str, self.entity))
```

Comment: That does not work like that. You do not UNDO the drawing. What you actually do is to draw white circle on top of the current drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not UNDO the drawing. What you actually do is to draw white circle on top of the current drawing.

Furthermore, the return value of [`pygame.draw.circle()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle) is not some kind of circle object, it is a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object, which encloses the circle.

When you draw an object, then you have to store the color, position and brush (`d_Ent.add((BLACK, (mouseX, mouseY), brush))`) in draw:

```py
def draw(window):
    if len(DrawEnt) > 0:
        d_Ent = DrawEnt[-1]

        mouseX, mouseY = pg.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pg.mouse.get_pressed()
        if click[0]:
            circle = pg.draw.circle(window, BLACK, (mouseX, mouseY), brush)
            d_Ent.add((BLACK, (mouseX, mouseY), brush))
```

When you want to "UNDO" some parts  of the drawing, then you have to clear the entire display and to redraw all the remaining objects:

```py
def main():
    # [...]

    while running:
        # [...]

        for event in pg.event.get():
            # [...]

            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:

                if event.key == pg.K_z and pg.key.get_mods() & pg.KMOD_LCTRL:

                    if len(DrawEnt) > 0:
                        ent = DrawEnt.pop()

                        window.fill((255, 255, 255))         
                        for drawent in DrawEnt:
                            for entity in drawent.entity:
                                pg.draw.circle(window, *entity)
```

[image]

Comment: may I ask how you specify those little gifs you're doing? do you have a software for that or is it a stackoverflow option? or do you record to mp4 and then convert to gif? that would help me in future question! thanks!

Comment: @SendHelp I use [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/), it is free, but it is for windows os only.

Comment: Great! I am using windows, thank you once again! :-)